# Informix with en_US.57372 character set gives an error for a LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX

Tags: informix

I am trying to read data from Informix DB using an ODBC driver.
Everything is just fine until I am trying to read a few characters such as ÂðŸ“ˆ'.

The ERR message I am having from the driver is `Error -21005` which is:
`"Invalid byte in codeset conversion input."`.

Is there a reason this char set is not able to read those characters? If so, is there a website (I haven't found one) where I can see the whole supported characters for this codeset?

Comment: Under `$INFORMIXDIR/gls`, you will find a file `cm3/registry` which identifies 57272 as `utf8` and also gives a code `0xe01c`.  There's also a file `cm3/e01c.cmo` which gives (in a somewhat obscure manner) the encodings.  For example, it contains the line `s 38 latin_capital_letter_a_with_circumflex 2 c382`. I'm not sure what the `s` and `38` mean, but the name is self-explanatory, `2` is the number of bytes needed to encode the character in UTF-8, and `c382` is the pair of bytes needed.  That translates to U+00C2, which in turn is the code for LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX.

Comment: Which version of the Informix ODBC driver are you using, and on which platform?  What exactly are you doing when the error occurs?  What is the `CLIENT_LOCALE` set to (is that `en_US.57372`)?  `DB_LOCALE`?  Which language are you writing in?

Comment: As Jonathan said, we need more details to be able to help.  On a select operation, error -21005 is usually a sign that either the data on the database table is wrong, or the locale environment is wrongly set on the client side.
Check out this tech note (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-21005-when-using-odbc-select-data-database). It explains why -21005 may appear

Answer (score 1):

This error -21005 could also mean that you have inserted invalid characters in your database due to your CLIENT_LOCALE being wrong, but this having not been detected by Informix because of it being set the same as DB_LOCALE, which prevented any conversion from having been done.

Then, when you try to read the data containing invalid characters, Informix would produce error -21005, to warn that some of the characters have been replaced by a placeholder, and therefore the data will not be reversible.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-21005-when-using-odbc-select-data-database for a detailed explanation on how an incorrect CLIENT_LOCALE can produce error -21005 when querying data.

CLIENT_LOCALE should always be set to the locale of the pc where your queries are being generated, and DB_LOCALE must match the locale with which the database was defined, and which you can find out with "SELECT tabname, site FROM systables WHERE tabid in (90, 91)" but beware that for example en_US.57372 would really mean en_us.utf8, you would need to look in gls\cm3\registry to see the mappings.

EDIT: The answer on [Queries problems using IBM Informix ODBC Driver in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343323/queries-problems-using-ibm-informix-odbc-driver-in-c-sharp?rq=1) also explains in great detail the misery a wrong CLIENT_LOCALE can bring, and how to fix it.